# Are multiple roles allowed in the @Secured annotation with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-security

I would like to allow access to a particular method to more than one group of users. Is it possible in Spring Security 3.x to do such a thing using the @Secured annotation? Consider two groups (roles) OPERATOR and USER, would this code be valid:

    `@Secured("ROLE_OPERATOR", "ROLE_USER")
    public void doWork() {
        // do useful processing
    }`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You're almost there. Syntactically, you need to write it like this:

```
@Secured({"ROLE_OPERATOR", "ROLE_USER"})
public void doWork() { ... }
```

This is because you're supplying multiple values to a single array attribute of the annotation. (Java syntactically special-cases handing in a single value, but now you need to do it “properly”.)

Comment: ... and to be specific, this is an (inclusive) `OR`, right? You will be authorized if you are a ROLE_OPERATOR, _or_ a ROLE_USER, _or_ both. It's not an `AND`.

Answer (score 20):

@Donal Fellows answer is correct for Spring apps.  However, if you're working in Grails, you need to use the Groovy syntax for lists so the code would look like this

```
@Secured(["ROLE_OPERATOR", "ROLE_USER"])
public void doWork() { ... }
```

Comment: People are awesome